# French Curtain Tie Backs

Tags: antique

How would one go about installing these french curtain tie backs? I don’t have the stake or dowels as in the link

https://www.ebay.com/itm/285065768857

[image]

Comment: Have you inquired of the seller?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you remove the pointy part (grey, rusty part) and hammer it in like a nail, and then push the front (brass) in.  The two pins at right angles snap onto the round holes in the brass.